# Troubles with starting value using UISlider

Tags: swift, uislider, xcode12

Started working on the application. There was the following problem, in Main.storyboard the current value is set for the slider (for the top one it is 1.5 out of 3, and for the bottom one it is 100 out of 200), therefore, [in the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0elh.jpg), I should have points on the slider track in the middle. I started googling about it, I can't find anything. Xcode 12 problem maybe? If not, please help me write the correct search query. I will be very grateful.
Sorry for my bad English. :)

Here ViewController:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var heightLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var weightLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }
    
    @IBAction func heightSliderChanged(_ sender: UISlider) {
        print(sender.value)
        heightLabel.text = String(format: "%.2f", sender.value) + "m"
    }

    @IBAction func weightSliderChanged(_ sender: UISlider) {
        weightLabel.text = String(format: "%.0f", sender.value) + "Kg"
    }
    
}
```

Property's for first slider:

[image: Property's for first slider]

Property's for second slider:

[image: Property's for second slider]

Comment: Can you add slider settings code ?

Comment: I'm supposing you are following a tutorial of i think her name yu or something lol, yes i did follow the same tutorial anyway post the code please so we can help

Comment: I only changed the ViewController. Nothing more

Comment: Where you set slider value? From storyboard? If yes then please attach property inspector screenshot for both slider.

Comment: Yes, from the storyboard. I have added images.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, it's Xcode issues. You can find the issues list from this link. (https://fahimfarook.medium.com/xcode-12-and-ios-14-developer-bugs-and-issues-ada35920a104).

Create an outlet of both slider and set value through coding.

```
@IBOutlet weak var firstSlider: UISlider!
@IBOutlet weak var secondSlider: UISlider!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    firstSlider.minimumValue = 0
    firstSlider.maximumValue = 3
    firstSlider.value = 1.5
    
    secondSlider.minimumValue = 0
    secondSlider.maximumValue = 200
    secondSlider.value = 100
}
```