# UISlider incorrectly defaulting to 1

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3

I'm using XCode 12.4, Swift 3.

I have created on my story board a `Label` and `UISlider` with default values.

I then have this code in my ViewController.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var slider: UISlider!
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        label.text = String(format: "%.2f", slider.value)
    }


    @IBAction func sliderChanged(_ sender: UISlider) {
        label.text = String(format: "%.2f", slider.value)
    }
}
```

Now when I run the code the `UISlider` it correctly defaults to 0.5 and in the middle of the slider.

[image: 0.5 Image displayed]

Next I change the `Minimum` to 0, `Maximum` to 200 and `value` to 100

[image: properties panel]

In XCode it shows the slider in the center.

[image: Xcode slider]

When I launch it however the slider defaults to 1.

[image: Default to 1 image.]

The same happens for any other combination of values except the default for the slider.

Now I can resolve this by updating the `viewDidLoad()` with `slider.value = 100` but I am trying to understand if this is expected behaviour or a bug I can fix within the storyboard?

Comment: does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65274464/14733292

Comment: @RajaKishan Perfect. Thanks.