# StoryboardUI how to make the label follow the slider

Tags: swift, storyboard

I'm doing a storyboardUI app. One part of the UI design is kind of like this:

[image]

I want the label position follows the slider position all the time, like below:

[image]

How can I do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assign this class to UISlider.

In this class created one label and change the position according to the slider thumb.

```
class ThumbTextSlider: UISlider {
    private var thumbTextLabel: UILabel = UILabel()
    
    private var thumbFrame: CGRect {
        return thumbRect(forBounds: bounds, trackRect: trackRect(forBounds: bounds), value: value)
    }
    
    private lazy var thumbView: UIView = {
        let thumb = UIView()
        return thumb
    }()
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        thumbTextLabel.frame = CGRect(x: thumbFrame.origin.x, y: thumbFrame.maxY - 5, width: thumbFrame.size.width, height: 30)
        self.setValue()
    }
    
    private func setValue() {
        thumbTextLabel.text = String(format: "%0.2f", self.value)
    }
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        addSubview(thumbTextLabel)
        thumbTextLabel.textAlignment = .center
        thumbTextLabel.textColor = .blue
        thumbTextLabel.layer.zPosition = layer.zPosition + 1
        thumbTextLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This looks promising. However when I paste the code into the project the the label still hasn't been shown.

Comment: Have you assigned this class to the UISlider controller? If yes then have you added any height constraint to the slider?

Comment: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIView 0x7fea94d05670> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key UISliderController.'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
CoreSimulator 732.18.6 - Device: iPhone SE (2nd generation) (EBD31BDC-336E-4C13-A4B5-31EF698284DD) - Runtime: iOS 14.4 (18D46) - DeviceType: iPhone SE (2nd generation)
(lldb)

Comment: after a couple of try the app just wouldn't let me to go anymore

Comment: Can you create one demo project and take a one slider and assign this class and check. might be a problem with your code.

Comment: I got it work now. Just one more question about how do I set the initial value for the UI slider?

Comment: If you feel this ans is useful then you can accept this and for your second question please check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65274464/14733292

Comment: thanks so much for the help Raja. Hope you have a nice day.